# HttpEntity is deprecated on Android now, what's the alternative?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

With the release of Android 5.1, it looks like all the Apache http stuff has been deprecated. Looking at the documentation is useless; they all say

`This class was deprecated in API level 22.
Please use openConnection() instead. Please visit this webpage for further details.`

Which is fine the first time you read it, but when EVERY class that was deprecated says that, it's not that helpful.

**Anyway, what are the alternatives for classes like `HttpEntity`, specifically `StringEntity`, and `MultipartEntity`?** I substituted `BasicNameValuePair` for my own implementation of Android's `Pair<T, S>` class, and it looks like `URLEncoder.encode` is a good substitute for `URLEncodedUtils`, but I'm not sure what to do about `HttpEntity`.

**EDIT**

I've decided just to re-write the networking stuff. Gonna try to use Retrofit and OkHttp

**EDIT**

Seriously take a look at switching your calls and stuff to Retrofit. Pretty nifty. I'm glad I did. There were a few hurdles, but it's cool.

Comment: You can have a look at [how to switch from HttpClient to HttpUrlConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898667/how-to-switch-from-httpclient-to-httpurlconnection/26903289#26903289)

Comment: If any of the answers below helped you out, you should accent the most helpful one.

Comment: Using `OkHttp` is wise choice.

Comment: HttpUrlConnection is the new standard (no external libraries required) way to do it. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030660/jsonparser-from-androidhive-tutorial-nosuchmethoderror-in-defaulthttpclient/33031158#33031158) for a good example implementing a json interface. The json can be stripped fairly easily if not needed. I had a horrible time getting Retrofit to work with Proguard and gave up.

Answer (score 21):

You can always import the last [Apache Http](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html) client and use that. Also, you might want to take a look at a networking library like [Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) or [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), just in case you can use that instead. If starting a new project, using a networking library is recommended because there is no need to reinvent the wheel. But if you are stuck with using `HttpClient`, then read on.

**EDIT: Latest news on Apache HttpClient (as of 11/07/2015)**

> Google Android 1.0 was released with a pre-BETA snapshot of Apache
>   HttpClient. To coincide with the first Android release Apache
>   HttpClient 4.0 APIs had to be frozen prematurely, while many of
>   interfaces and internal structures were still not fully worked out. As
>   Apache HttpClient 4.0 was maturing the project was expecting Google to
>   incorporate the latest code improvements into their code tree.
>   Unfortunately it did not happen. Version of Apache HttpClient shipped
>   with Android has effectively become a fork. Eventually Google decided
>   to discontinue further development of their fork while refusing to
>   upgrade to the stock version of Apache HttpClient citing compatibility
>   concerns as a reason for such decision. As a result those Android
>   developers who would like to continue using Apache HttpClient APIs on
>   Android cannot take advantage of newer features, performance
>   improvements and bug fixes. Apache HttpClient 4.3 port for Android was
>   intended to remedy the situation by providing official releases
>   compatible with Google Android. Given that as of Android API 23
>   Google's fork of HttpClient has been removed this project has been
>   discontinued.

*However, there is an official Android port of the Apache HttpClient v4.3*

***Android API 22 and older*** should use the Apache HttpClient v4.3

```
dependencies {
         compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1' 
}
```

**Android API 23 and newer** should use Apache HttpClient packages for Android [maintained by Marek Sebera](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android/wiki/Project-Introduction)

```
dependencies {
     compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1' 
}
```

Info taken from [Apache.org](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html)

Comment: As it wasn't obvious to me: You also have to change `import org.apache.http.whatever` to `import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.whatever`.

Comment: It seems 'cz.msebera.android' httpclient is also deprecated now? When trying to build APK Android Studio fails and alerts that httpclient now conflicts with classes provided by Android

Answer (score 12):

The [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) documentation points you in the right direction:

`org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`:

> This interface was deprecated in API level 22.
>   Please use openConnection() instead. Please visit this webpage for further details.

means that you should switch to `java.net.URL.openConnection()`.

Here's how you could do it:

```
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://some-server");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

// read the response
System.out.println("Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
String response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: you might be right for http client part ... the comment is absolutely ridiculous for the http server part  ( or is URL.openConnection now able to serve too?! ;-)

Comment: If you read This URL.  
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

**Which client is best?**
**Apache HTTP client has fewer bugs on Eclair and Froyo. It is the best choice for these releases.**

**For Gingerbread and better, HttpURLConnection is the best choice.** Its simple API and small size makes it great fit for Android. Transparent compression and response caching reduce network use, improve speed and save battery. New applications should use HttpURLConnection; it is where we will be spending our energy going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Call webservice httpclient replace by httpurlconnection

my code here

```
public static String getDataFromUrl(String url) {
        String result = null;
//        System.out.println("URL comes in jsonparser class is:  " + url);
        try {
            URL myurl=new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myurl
                    .openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream is=urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (is != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is));
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                } finally {
                  is.close();
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            result=null;
        }
        return result;
    }
```