# Get text from a URL using Android HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

how can i get the content of the URLbelow using `HttpURLConnection` and put it in a `TextView`?

http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8655039/5202007

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Http Get using Android HttpURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654876/http-get-using-android-httpurlconnection)

Comment: thanks i seen this before asking but it doesn't help me 
the content in the url is 
"TUTORIAL 20 WORKED, WE GOT CONNECTION"
and i want to get this text from url then put it in a text view

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(code==200){
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                if (in != null) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        result += line;
                }
                in.close();
            }

            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        yourTextView.setText(result);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

and call this class by using

```
new GetData().execute();
```

Comment: thanks man it's worked
but can i do that without create a class?

Comment: it is network operation and must be perform on separate thread. So you need the asyncTask class. Because asynctask is the best option to perform network operations.

Comment: Depreciated now

Comment: @Jamil Check the documentation. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: @DeepakGoyal : Yep already seen it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150184/httpentity-is-deprecated-on-android-now-whats-the-alternative

Comment: @Jamil Its `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` which was depreceated but `HttpURLConnection` is the overcome of that.