# Cannot Resolve Symbol HttpEntity,HttpResponse

Tags: android, xml-parsing, androidhttpclient

I am trying to learn XML parsing using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) tutorial but some of the classes are not getting imported. Here is the code:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(uri);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

These classes are not getting imported:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

My Gradle properties:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rr.rio"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Bad, bad...  please stop using sockpupet accounts for serial upvoting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`HTTP client` is deprecated on sdk 23, use `HttpURLConnection` instead

or add this to your gradle (not recommended)

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String urlString) {
    String xml = null;

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isw);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        br.close();

        xml = sb.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: Can we use HttpURLConnection for Xml Parsing? @NaviRamyle

Comment: can u provide Link or Ideas plz! @NaviRamyle

Comment: I'll make an example same as Android Hive but using HttpURLConnection, please wait.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this in build.gradle(Module: app):
HttpClient is not supported in sdk 23. Either you have to use URLConnection or downgrade to sdk 22.

OR

If you need sdk 23, add this to your gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `org.apache.http` got removed in API 23.
If you want to use it for learning, use a lower API, or find alternatives. See this link: [HttpEntity is deprecated on Android now, what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150184/httpentity-is-deprecated-on-android-now-whats-the-alternative)