# NSURLSession equivalent in Android?

Tags: android, httpclient, httpurlconnection, nsurlsession

I need to send **HTTP POST** message in Android. I have seen many [way](http://hayageek.com/android-http-post-get/) to do it. But the accepted answers are using deprecated classes, or approachas are far from the most efficient solutions. Apple moved from `NSURLConnection` to `NSURLSession`. Is it any similar framework in Android too?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android) that i.e. `HttpUrlConnection` and `HttpClient` are not recommended to use, but I do not want to use 3rd party library.

Comment: Please consider using a plug-in such as Retrofit, Volley or such. No need to reinvent the wheel. all of those plug-ins will do any requests (GET, POST, etc) asynchronously and provide JSON mapping, and will save you a ton of boilerplate code. Welcome to Android development!

Comment: What you mean plug-in? I am looking for **standard** class / framework. No 3rd party solution. It is written in the question.

Comment: Hence I went with "please consider" and a comment, not an answer. If you cant' or don't want to use a 3rd party solution, just wait for actual answers.

Comment: Just for the record, would you consider Google a 3rd party? Because they are the ones maintaining Volley (https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: If you change your mind, then you could perhaps take a look at http://square.github.io/okhttp/ or one of the other 3rd party suggestions that has already been mentioned like Volley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have much choice.

`HttpClient` is deprecated, but still works.

`HttpUrlConnection`  is ok, if you dont have plan to write app for dinosaurs. I use it anyway in corporate app android 2.3+ and dont have problems with it.

Or 3rd party libraries like `Retrofit` or `Volley`.

There are other ways but they are even worse than just 3rd party library, like using Android NDK.

Comment: There's a way to import a more current version of `HttpClient`, but it was made by Apache, so a 3rd party. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150184/httpentity-is-deprecated-on-android-now-whats-the-alternative/29150361#29150361

Comment: well if you are ready to import something, Retrofit is better, if not just use HttpUrlConnection, srsly I dont think you use something that hard for it.

Comment: if we are talking about ways, you can import cURL to android NDK for example, but its not best decision still.

Comment: That's not the same because the default `HttpClient` client that was bundled with Android was actually a forked Apache `HttpClient` that wasn't really maintained. So importing a new version is seems closer to the original client.