# Can I import an image from any type of website?

Tags: java, image, url, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to import images from Internet using Java (IDE IntelliJ) but I don't know how to select an image (in this case the first of the row) from google images.
For example I tried to search the capital of Rome and Napoli, but the code can't find any image from images google's section.

Probably you don't understand much what I said, so below you will find the code I wrote with the relative error

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] listaCapitali = {
            "Roma",
            "Napoli",

    };

    for (String capitale : listaCapitali) {
        ricercaGoogle("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + capitale + "+cartina&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-moK1y-D0AhXIzaQKHeXUBLUQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&cshid=1639392166213289&biw=2240&bih=1082&dpr=2");

    }
  }

private static void ricercaGoogle(String urlPath) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int response = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(response);

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(image));
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The error says:

```
403
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
at Main.ricercaGoogle(Main.java:33)
at Main.main(Main.java:19)

403
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
at Main.ricercaGoogle(Main.java:33)
at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Could you also help me to download those images on my computer named with the capital name? Thanks a lot

Comment: First of all, the 403 (Forbidden) response code indicates you try do something Goggle won't let you do. Not sure if their terms allow scraping. Second, when you search  on the internet, you typically get back HTML. You need to parse that HTML to get the URL to the images. Finally, when you have the image URLs, simply download and write the image files directly to disk, without decoding them (as `ImageIO.read(..)` does).

Answer (score 0):

**First thing to do :Your URL is not an URL of an Image ! try to change the URL**

***You can inspire from that code it works fine :***
Get an image from a HTTPGET and Put it on a file

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
                
                /*
                 * put your urlPath here instead of http://localhost...
                 */
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9090/imageFilm/1");

             
                // Execute and get the response.
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {
                    try (InputStream instream = entity.getContent()) {

                    // receiving an image and write it within a file 

                        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                                /*
                                 * here i create a file with the image received from the httpGet , you can do other things 
                                 */
                                new File("C:\\Users\\OUSSAMA\\Desktop\\xc.png"), false)) {
                            int read;
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                            while ((read = instream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

**Apache HttpClient dependency needed :**
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13

---

> All The code in one class :

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] listaCapitali = {
            "Roma",
            "Napoli",

    };

    for (String capitale : listaCapitali) {
        //ricercaGoogle("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + capitale + "+cartina&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-moK1y-D0AhXIzaQKHeXUBLUQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&cshid=1639392166213289&biw=2240&bih=1082&dpr=2");//Your URL is not an URL of an Image ; you must change it !
             ricercaGoogle("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1b/75/84/1b758419a811ae05ad4da61acdb7ce22.jpg");
    }
  }

private static void ricercaGoogle(String urlPath) {
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    
    /*
     * put your urlPath here instead of http://localhost...
     */
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlPath);

     // Execute and get the response.
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {
        try (InputStream instream = entity.getContent()) {

        // receiving an image and write it within a file 
             try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    /*
                     * here i create a file with the image received from the httpGet , you can do other things 
                     */
                    new File("C:\\Users\\Mourad\\Desktop\\xc.png"), false)) {
                int read;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while ((read = instream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
 
}
```

Comment: Where can I import those classes? IntelliJ it doesn't make me do it

Comment: @FrancescoZanoncelli Answer updated with Maven dependency of Apache HttpClient , Also your URL is not an µURL of an Image , all the code in one class , i tested it here and it works fine

Comment: This error came out: `httpclient` defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for `httpclient` use `HttpUrlConnection` or `okhttp` instead), or repackaging the library using something like `jarjar`.

Comment: @FrancescoZanoncelli you can use HttpUrlConnection , try to read the documentation and use the same approche , this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898667/how-to-switch-from-httpclient-to-httpurlconnection   // and this answer too :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54355038/lint-error-httpclient-defines-classes-that-conflict-with-classes-now-provided